# Create a new column based on conditional count of other column grouped by id

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like this:
My goal is to count the number of countries grouped by id but only (usa, canada, mex)

| id | country | desired_output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | usa | 1 |
| b | canada | 2 |
| b | canada | 2 |
| c | china | 0 |
| d | mexico | 3 |
| d | mexico | 3 |
| d | mexico | 3 |

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Convert `id` or some another column to `NaN` in [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) and [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and then count non `NaN`s rows by [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html):

```
L = ["usa","canada","mexico"]
df['desired_output'] = df.id.where(df.country.isin(L)).groupby(df['id']).transform('count')
print (df)
  id country  desired_output
0  a     usa               1
1  b  canada               2
2  b  canada               2
3  c   china               0
4  d  mexico               3
5  d  mexico               3
6  d  mexico               3
```